# How to render checkbox from an array of array in React

Tags: arrays, reactjs, checkbox, nested, frontend

I am new to react. I am working on a project where I want to render checkboxes from an array that is coming from API response, where based on the phrase matching I have to group the options. i.e if item contains "BLR" it will group to all "BLR-" items

API response is :

```
[
    "AU-COPS",
    "BLR",
    "BLR- End to End ACT testers",
    "BLR-ACT-FUNCTIONAL",
    "BLR-ACT-POLICY",
    "BLR-ASM",
    "BLR-ASM-FUNCTIONAL",
    "BLR-ASM-POLICY",
    "BLR-DAG",
    "BLR-DEMO",
    "BLR-MANAGED",
    "BLR-QI",
    "BLR-TOOLS",
    "DE-COPS",
    "demo-1",
    "demo-2",
    "ES- Audit (S&Q)",
    "ES- Managed",
    "ES-COPS",
    "ES-Functional (managed/unmanaged)",
    "FR- Audit (S&Q)",
    "FR- Functional (managed/unmanaged)",
    "FR-COPS",
    "FR-Managed",
    "IT- Functional (managed/unmanaged)",
    "IT- Managed",
    "IT-Audit (S&Q)",
    "IT-COPS",
    "JP-COPS",
    "SEA-MANAGED",
    "SJO-COPS",
]
```

For grouping, I have created one more array
`var ch = ["BLR", "UK", "IT", "ES", "SEA"]`

my code to render check box:

```
<div>
  {listOfCheckboxes &&
    checkBoxHeading.map((item, index) => {
      return (
        <>
          <h8>{item}</h8>
          <div key={index}>
            {listOfCheckboxes.filter((childItem, childIndex) => {
              if (childItem.includes(item))
                return (
                  <div key={childIndex}>
                    <label htmlFor={childItem}>{childItem}</label>
                    <input
                      type="checkbox"
                      id={childItem}
                      name={childItem}
                      value={childItem}
                    ></input>
                  </div>
                );
            })}
          </div>
        </>
      );
    })}
</div>;
```

Please help me guys!!

The output I am getting is listed all items without checkboxes.

Comment: wrong use of filter. Filter should return only true/false. I guess you are trying to use .map

Comment: What is `checkBoxHeading` and `listOfCheckboxes`. @SomeoneSpecial is correct. You are mixing `.map` with `.filter`. Filter callback needs to return a value that coerces to true to keep the element, or to false otherwise.

Comment: checkBoxHeading is ["BLR", "UK", "IT", "ES", "SEA"] and listOfCheckboxes is the array coming from API response. I need to group the check boxes where BLR heading will contain all the "BLR"  related checkboxes, ES contain all the "ES" related and so on. I may be doing wrong. @UXNomaan please help me.

Comment: @SomeoneSpecial, I have tried with map and it is working fine. It is able to return me the checkboxes as expected. Logic remains same only I have replaced "map" instead of filter. Thank you for pointing out the issue.

Comment: so i guess issue resolved?

Comment: Yes It is resolved  now. Thanks for helping :)